# How to move double nested embedded Mongoid documents between single embedded Mongoid documents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, mongoid3

Expanding on the examples in the Mongoid relations documentation, let's say I have three classes...

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :albums
end

class Album
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  embedded_in :band
  embeds_many :tracks
end

class Track
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :length, type: String
  embedded_in :album
end
```

How can I move a track from one album to another? I've tried the obvious...

```
~/Projects/mongoid_testing (development) > Band.last.albums.first.tracks.first.update_attribute :album_id, Band.last.albums.second.id
☘ MongoDB (8ms) [mongoid_testing_development::Bands] QUERY selector={"$query"=>{}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>-1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil
☘ MongoDB (0ms) [mongoid_testing_development::Bands] QUERY selector={"$query"=>{}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>-1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil
☘ MongoDB (0ms) [mongoid_testing_development::Bands] UPDATE selector={"_id"=>"51005ceb93e53c2eec000012"} update={"$set"=>{"albums.0.tracks.0.album_id"=>"51005d2993e53c2eec000017"}} flags=[]
=> true
~/Projects/mongoid_testing (development) > Band.last
☘ MongoDB (0ms) [mongoid_testing_development::Bands] QUERY selector={"$query"=>{}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>-1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil
=> #<Band:0x007fa22725b1f8> {
           :_id => "51005ceb93e53c2eec000012",
      :albums => [
        [0] {
               "_id" => "51005d2293e53c2eec000016",
            "tracks" => [
                [0] {
                         "_id" => "5107d87993e53c7191000007",
                    "album_id" => "51005d2993e53c2eec000017",
                       "title" => "Pipeline"
                }
            ],
              "name" => "Violater"
        },
        [1] {
             "_id" => "51005d2993e53c2eec000017",
            "name" => "Construction Time Again"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I've tried the not so obvious...

```
class Track
  ...
  def move_to(new_album_id)
    _parent.albums.delete self
    _root.albums.find(new_album_id).tracks.push self
  end
end
```

But no matter what I can't seem to re-associate double nested embedded documents. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Regarding your first try, correct me if I'm wrong but I'm pretty sure that the objects are not related using an id like they would in a relational database, with a foreign key constraint etc... cause they are embedded documents. I recently used Mongoid and I'm pretty sure I've done something similar like so : `new_album.tracks << track_to_move`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the solution

```
new_parent = Band.first.albums.second
old_track = Band.first.albums.first.tracks.first

unless new_parent.id == old_track.parent.id
  new_parent.tracks << old_track.dup
  old_track.delete
end
```

Comment: This is almost what I've been looking for. However, I wonder if it's possible to achieve the same without changing the id of the embedded document

Comment: Oh, I've figured this out. I just do old_track.update_attribute(:id, new_track.id) right after duplicating the old track